# array of element id with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm new in Javascript and need your help here.
I want to have an array of element Ids for next usage.

Example:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="checkboxes" value="checkbox1_v">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" class="checkboxes" value="checkbox2_v">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" class="checkboxes" value="checkbox3_v">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" class="checkboxes" value="checkbox4_v">
</div>
```

What I need is an array like this ("checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, checkbox4") to set to var for use in next js function that show/hide div if appropriate checkbox is checked (using forEach to check every checkbox and if selected than set .show to div).

Show/hide part of js i have and  in testing it works fine for one specific checkbox. But the reason for having array is that number of checkboxes is dynamic and common attributes are only "myDiv" for outer div and input class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to generate such an array like

```
var ids = $('#myDiv .checkboxes').map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

In this case it generates an array with ids of all elements with the class checkboxes

Comment: +1 - personally I'd do `[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".checkboxes"),function(c) {return c.id;})` but whatever gets the job done :p

Comment: In any case, I'd give you a +2 if I could just because you actually wrote `this.id` instead of the soul-crushing `$(this).attr("id")` or heaven forbid `$("#"+this.id).attr("id")`...

Comment: Then please mark this answer as the selected one, to mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)**:

> Pass each element in the current matched set through a function,
>   producing a new jQuery object containing the return values.

```
var idArr = $('#myDiv input[type="checkbox"]').map(function() {
    return this.id
}).get();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aGy66/)**